# Reading Newly Added Contents from Compressed Log File (log4j) using Boost's Zstd Filtering Stream

Tags: c++, boost, zstd

I'm currently working on a C++ program aimed at tailing a live log file stored on disk. The catch is that the log file is compressed using Zstd. I've been using Boost's (1.83) Zstd filtering stream for decompression, but I've hit a roadblock. It seems that the filtering stream isn't picking up newly added contents to the log file.

I've tried troubleshooting this issue but haven't had much luck. Does anyone have experience with this or know of any resources I could consult for guidance? I have added how my code looks like below.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions you can provide!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp> // Example filter (can be replaced with any filter)
#include <fstream>
#include <zstd.h>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;

int main() {
    // Create a filtering_istreambuf with a zlib decompressor
    io::filtering_streambuf<io::input> in;
    in.push(io::zstd_decompressor());
    std::ifstream file("compressed_file.txt.zst", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    in.push(file);
    // Construct an istream from the underlying streambuf
    std::istream inputStream(&in);
    // Read lines from the input stream using std::getline()

    while (true) {

        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(inputStream, line)) {
            std::cout << "Line: " << line << std::endl;
        }

        if (inputStream.eof()) {
            inputStream.clear();
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At the very least you need to seek back to the beginning of your stream after calling `file.clear()`. But since one process is reading from a file while another process is writing to it you might be better advised to actually close and reopen the file.

Comment: zlib is not Zstd.

Comment: Are you able to tail a regular text file? Because that seems to be your entire issue. You need a stream that doesn't EOF but waits for the file to grow. The decompression is largely irrelevant.

Comment: @john unfortunately we can't open/close the file as it will increase the i/o. How do i seek back to the point so that I don't consume duplicate data?

Comment: @sehe yes. If I remove `in.push(io::zstd_decompressor());` it works fine. I am able to append lines to the file and my program reads it

Comment: @SelvaramG how? It shouldn't work, and it doesn't for me (linux): https://imgur.com/a/ZcQCs9h

Comment: @sehe sorry there was a small correction in the code, I modified it now. This works when I remove the line `in.push(io::zstd_decompressor());` for tailing live text

Comment: @SelvaramG Ooh yeah, like that I sort-of understand, though it really highlights the problem with doing a poor-man's tail: it busy-spins a CPU at close to 100% all the time waiting for new input to arrive: https://imgur.com/a/JpR5QGY (it also doesn't start following a new file like with `tail -F`)

Answer (score 0):

I think decompression isn't your issue here. It's merely what **manifests** your issue. Even without decompression you'd run into the same problem: the stream stops at EOF.

It doesn't immediately look like `iostreams` has a facility like tail, but you can always use... `tail`:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fa1021dc47ad93f)**

```cpp
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::string_literals;
namespace bp = boost::process;
namespace io = boost::iostreams;

int main() {
    bp::ipstream monitor;
    bp::child    tail("/usr/bin/tail",                               //
                      std::vector{"-f"s, "compressed_file.txt.gz"s}, //
                      bp::std_in.null(),                             //
                      bp::std_out = monitor);

    io::filtering_istream filter;
    filter.push(io::gzip_decompressor{});
    filter.push(monitor);

    for (std::string line; getline(filter, line);)
        std::cout << "line: " << line << "\n";

    tail.wait();
}
```

Testing with

```
gzip -k main.cpp; mv main.cpp.gz compressed_file.txt.gz
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lz -lboost_iostreams 
./a.out
```

Prints the expected:

```
line: #include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
line: #include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
line: #include <boost/process.hpp>
line: #include <iostream>
line: using namespace std::string_literals;
line: namespace bp = boost::process;
line: namespace io = boost::iostreams;
line: 
line: int main() {
line:     bp::ipstream monitor;
line:     bp::child    tail("/usr/bin/tail",                        //
line:                       std::vector{"compressed_file.txt.gz"s}, //
line:                       bp::std_in.null(),                      //
line:                       bp::std_out = monitor);
line: 
line:     io::filtering_istream filter;
line:     filter.push(io::gzip_decompressor{});
line:     filter.push(monitor);
line: 
line:     for (std::string line; getline(filter, line);)
line:         std::cout << "line: " << line << "\n";
line: 
line:     tail.wait();
line: }
```

### BONUS

Of course, dropping link dependencies on boost Boost IOstream and zlib consider:

```cpp
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::string_literals;
namespace bp = boost::process;

int main() {
    bp::pstream tail_out, unzip_out;
    bp::child                                       //
        tail("/usr/bin/tail",                       //
             std::vector{"-f"s},                    //
             bp::std_in < "compressed_file.txt.gz", //
             bp::std_out = tail_out),               //
        unzip("/usr/bin/zcat",                      //
              bp::std_in  = tail_out,               //
              bp::std_out = unzip_out);

    for (std::string line; getline(unzip_out, line);)
        std::cout << "line: " << line << "\n";

    return unzip.exit_code();
}
```

Still the same effect. Of course even simpler:

```cpp
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace bp = boost::process;

int main() {
    bp::pstream stream;
    bp::child pipeline("tail -f | zcat", bp::shell, bp::std_in < "compressed_file.txt.gz", bp::std_out = stream);

    for (std::string line; getline(stream, line);)
        std::cout << "line: " << line << "\n";

    return pipeline.exit_code();
}
```

Printing

```
line: #include <boost/process.hpp>
line: #include <iostream>
line: namespace bp = boost::process;
line: 
line: int main() {
line:     bp::pstream stream;
line:     bp::child pipeline("tail | zcat", bp::shell, bp::std_in < "compressed_file.txt.gz", bp::std_out = stream);
line: 
line:     for (std::string line; getline(stream, line);)
line:         std::cout << "line: " << line << "\n";
line: 
line:     return pipeline.exit_code();
line: }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this. Is there any performance implications for using tail()?

Comment: There's always performance implications. However, you can trust that `tail` is pretty darn optimized. On posix, it's exactly as cheap as a thread, so I don't think you can beat it performance-wise.

Comment: tail does get the last few lines but does not pickup new lines. I am looking for `tail -f`'s functionality instead. How can I achieve that?

Comment: oh shute. I completely forgot to add `-f` there. Yeah, without it, it doesn't really make sense!

Comment: All three examples amended. Sorry for that oversight